# Is maintain the transaction with a static LINQ to SQL DataContext in asp.net possible?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql, static

I have ASP.NET application which is connected with SQL server using LINQ to SQL. Where as i have a static class , certainly it would work on application level. Where as I have created static object of `DataContext` in this static class. 
I have not created any data context object in application except this. Where as i am using this static data context object for each data base manipulation.

So will this maintain the transaction as thread-safe for each logged in user?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Note: the following advice holds for all O/RM tools that implement the unit of work pattern such as Entity Framework's `ObjectContext`, `DbContext`, NHibernate's `Session`, and LINQ to SQL's `DataContext`.*

The LINQ to SQL DataContext is NOT thread-safe. You should create (at least) 1 context per web request. Reusing the same instance over multiple threads means that one thread can call `SubmitChanges` while another thread is still inserting new objects. If you're lucky the `DataContext` will throw an exception, because it cannot persist the changes. If you're unlucky, the `DataContext` succeeds and you break the atomicy of a single request, which can cause you to have inconsistent data in your database. In other words: You'll have a database full of shit!

Besides that, the `DataContext` keeps all objects in its cache, which mean that the memory consumption of your application will keep growing, which can lead to an `OutOfMemoryException` (OOM). And even if you won’t get an OOM, the objects in the cache get stale and especially if other applications or processes are updating your database, you will never see those changes when an entity is already in memory. And last thing to note is that there is no way for you to rollback changes made in the `DataContext` so when you (at one point) invalidated the `DataContext` (because of errors) there is no way to restore this (except from creating a totally new `DataContext`). In that case your AppDomain is doomed.

Answer (score -1):

Your decision to use single DataContext object is not optimal. Create them whenever you need one (transaction). http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/246222.aspx

Comment: 'optimal' is an understatement :-)

Comment: what does mean her by 'optimal' really?

Comment: 'not optimal' is simply a false statement, because it is impossible to use a single `DataContext` in a multi-threaded environment. Even the referenced article describes this.

Comment: @Steven .you do you mean we can not use static DataContext variable in web application ? in my application i have never maintain any king of thread safe code up till now. please suggest me. My application is about to deliver . and i am using static datacontext variable. what i have to do ?

Comment: @Latit: "My application is about to deliver". Don't deliver! I'm serious. Do not! Once your application is in production, it will simply fail horribly and will be unstrustable or even unusable. Using a single `DataContext` instance throughout your complete web application is simply **impossible**.