# Should I only use one DataContext?

Tags: asp.net, linq-to-sql

I am new to .NET and LINQ to SQL.

So far, I have been pulling data and populating a gridview, and everything is working fine.

However, when I built my second page, I created a new DataContext (I assumed using one per page)  when I referenced a table that I used in my previous page, it gave me an "Ambiguous reference" error because I had my table in both DataContexts.  After removing the table from the second, I could reference the one from my first.

So, should I have just one context for my entire application or one for each table?  Maybe something in between where I put the tables that I **mostly** use together in the same context?

What is the best practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In LINQ to SQL the DataContext serves as an abstraction of the database. If I'm understanding your question correctly, you had been using two separate classes that defined unique DataContexts per page? You need only one DataContext class that can be shared in the application. If you really wanted to, you could have multiple instances of the DataContext but I can't think of when you'd want to do that.

If you have code of how you're accessing the DataContext and tables it would help.

See the MSDN reference on the DataContext class - [DataContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.aspx) for more information.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I had to down vote the answer, because you advised to have a single `DataContext` per application, which is an absolute sin in a multi-threaded application, such as ASP.NET. The `DataContext` is *not* thread-safe, and you will end up with an application that will fail miserably. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5324147/is-maintain-the-transaction-with-a-static-linq-to-sql-datacontext-in-asp-net-poss/5324377#5324377.

Comment: Single DataContext *class*. I didn't mean to imply it should be implemented as a Singleton. It sounds to me like the OP has tried creating multiple classes using DataContext. I would have advised using a DI container to hand out contexts per request but it seemed out of scope for the question.

Comment: Ok, I am confused on what you two are arguing on.  So I can put all my tables into a single datacontext, but I need to avoid calling it in a specific way?

Comment: Stevens point was that the application instance should not have one DataContext that all visitors share. Probably due to the way I worded my response. What I meant was you need only one class that has a DataContext and knows how to access any tables in your underlying database. That class can be instantiated and passed into any pages that need it.

Comment: Gotcha.  Was never thinking of referenceing it that way!  Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Ahh.. Yes, define a single DataContext, but create new instances of that type for each request. If that's what you mean, I will undo my downvote (please update your answer, so I can upvote it).

Comment: @Brian - Thanks for cleaning that up for me.

Answer (score 5):

It's not entirely clear if your asking (1) how many DataContext classes you should write or (2) how many times you should "new up" (instantiate) a DataContext class.

If it's (1), you want to write *one* DataContext class for your whole application unless your app is using more than one database.

If it's (2), you will generally want to instantiate one instance of a DataContext per *request*, which basically means one per page.

Comment: Its number 1.  Even with my limited knowledge of .Net, I would never think of trying to initiate one instance on the class for the whole tool!

Answer (score 3):

I think the best practice is to use one datacontext - once you start mixing datacontexts and DBML files in the same project, sometimes using the same tables, etc., thinks start to get wonky with namespacing in the datacontext.

Comment: Doesnt that cause issue when creating applications with large database structures?

Comment: The DataContext doesn't pull in all of the information in your database if that's what you're thinking. It prepares commands based on your LINQ queries and only executes at the last possible moment, requesting only what data you require. It doesn't matter (to some degree) how large the database structures are if you're only asking for what you need to display on the page.

Comment: I edited my answer as a result of the downvote. You're right about the thread safety - however, the question was whether you can make multiple DBML files with similar tables in them. Unless someone has a better answer, you can't do it. The issue with large database structures is that the DBML gets really crowded and difficult to follow. Otherwise it's ok. Just out of curiousity, why Linq instead of maybe Simple.Data, Massive, EF or some other ORM tool?

Comment: I am really new to .Net (I think this is day 3 for me) and I'm using linq to SQl cause the .net developers in my office said to start there.  Eventually i will look into entity framwork, but not till i know more of what i am doing.

Comment: I would honestly say that using Massive or Simple.Net is easier than Linq to SQL. Does require. NET 4.0 though.