# Dependencies registration in Application_BeginRequest() method

Tags: asp.net, .net, dependency-injection, unity-container, ioc-container

Is this normal to write the following code:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest()
{
    var container = new UnityContainer()
        .RegisterType<IUnitOfWork, MyEntities>()

    HttpContext.Current.Items["container"] = container;

    ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(
        () => new UnityServiceLocator(container));
}

protected void Application_EndRequest()
{
    var container = HttpContext.Current.Items["container"] 
        as UnityContainer;

    if (container != null)
    {
        container.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Or registering dependencies for every request is a bad practice?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *Note: the following advice holds for all IoC frameworks and is not specific to Unity.*

**TLDR**: don't do this. Register the container once in `Application_Start` and call `ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider` just once.

It is fine to register dependencies to have a 'per request' or 'per web request' lifetime. Creating a new container instance per web request however, is a ***very bad*** practice.

Containers are optimized for resolving instances (not for registering), which often means there is some dynamic code generation going on under the covers when a type is requested (from the container) for the first time. The registration and code generation and compilation process can be pretty time consuming, and creating a new instance of the container on each web request, will trigger the complete registration and code generation process all over again. This takes time, generates many temporary objects (more garbage to be collected), and generates new code that must be cached at least during the lifetime of that container instance.

Further more, having multiple container instances, makes it hard to do other optimizations, such as registering instances with a bigger scope than per web request. In your case, registering a type as 'singleton' practically means 'per web request', since that type is singleton within the context of that container instance. Or even without performance as a consideration, for some types to work correctly, you'll need a lifetime larger than 'per web request' (such as one instance per app domain), which is harder to configure.

You probably can do this, even with a container per request, but your code will be much harder to maintain.

The container itself is thread-safe, so there is in that sense no need to have container instance per request.

And in your case it is even worse, since you have a **race condition**, a **concurrency bug**, in your code, since you change the `ServiceLocator` on each request. The `ServiceLocator` stores the registered delegate in a private static field, which means it is accessible from all threads. In other words, you are sharing container instances over web requests. You probably won't notice during development, since you will be having one web request at the time, but when you have code calling `ServiceLocator.Current`, it will fail in production. Take for instance the following very likely scenario where request 1 starts and sets the service locator. After that, request 2 starts and overrides the service locator with it's own container instance. After that, code in request 1 calls `ServiceLocator.Current` which now returns the container of the second request. Sometimes (if you're lucky) you'll get an `ObjectDisposedException`. This will happen if a thread disposes its container that another thread is still (incorrectly) using. Sometimes however, types are resolved that belong to a different web request (instances that are unsafe to be used over multiple threads), which is obviously bad and causes all kinds of strange and incorrect behavior. For instance when you return a LINQ to SQL `DataContext` or Entity Framework `ObjectContext` instance. Those classes should normally be configured per web request and [can't be shared by multiple threads](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5324377/264697).

Comment: If there was a way to separate the registration and the dynamic type building parts in the container, would you still advise against using the per request container instance? I stumbled on this post searching this because it just feels much more correct to have the container scoped to the request in a web application, it's a stateless world after all. The fact that the objects are not disposed until much later is enough to convince me that a container per request is a much smarted thing at least in terms of resources.

Comment: @julealgon: What you're basically saying is "if the container wouldn't do any optimizations at all, would you still advice against this". The answer is yes. Without any optimizations the framework will be quite slow, and there will still be a lot of overhead in registering instances on each request. And if the container is that slow, it becomes even more importantly to optimize by using per-app-domain scoped instances, but this is much harder to register when you have a container per request and this hinders maintainability.

Comment: @julealgon: And about state: if you register all components as transient, there will effectively be no state in the container, since each Resolve would build a complete new set of objects. You can get this same statelessness with a single container. And having a single container with per-web-request registrations gives the same sort of state and behavior as a container-per-web-request gives you, only with much higher performance. And btw, I have never seen complete stateless web applications. There is always some cache, some singletons (and don't forget: some database).

Comment: @julealgon: And if you fear the chance of incorrectly wired components (for instance, accidentally having singletons wired with per-web-request dependencies), you should be definitely start looking for a different DI framework, since there are frameworks that can diagnose the container configuration for you an spot this kind of misconfigurations. Unity lacks such feature, but other frameworks such as Simple Injector can do this for you ([example](https://simpleinjector.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Diagnostics)).